# Body parser in node

Tags: javascript, node.js, body-parser

I'm usind body parser

```
app.use(bodyParser.json())
```

and when I receive some data on this route

```
saveTest = function(req, res){
            
            console.log(req.body);
        }
```

With this ajax request

```
var json_test = JSON.stringify(test);
    $.ajax({
        url:'/guardar-test',
        method:'POST',
        data: json_test
    });
```

I expected that if I send and object , the data will be parsed to json automatically but is not this way I I have to use `stringify` function, its something wrong?

Comment: `stringify` is used to construct JSON.

Comment: I know but Ithought that I dont need it if I user `body-parser`

Comment: What is your question?  I'm confused.  Your current `$.ajax()` code is sending plain text with a content-type of `text/plain`.  There's no way for the server to know that's 
supposed to be JSON so therefore `bodyParser.json()` doesn't do anything to the incoming request (because it's not marked as a JSON content-type).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set `contentType` option to `application/json` while using `$.ajax`.